# Replace classes within a click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, replace

I need to replace some class names within a click function.

I have this line of code, which adds the correct class when a button is clicked:

```
showLeft.onclick = function() {
    $(".cbp-spmenu-open ul li.inview").toggleClass("animated bounceInLeft visible");
};
```

When I click the button again, how can I replace the above class names with the following: `animated bounceOutLeft hidden` and vice-versa?

Comment: better to have a if condition & use addclass & removeClass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this one

```
showLeft.onclick = function() {
    $(".cbp-spmenu-open ul li.inview").toggleClass('bounceInLeft visible').toggleClass('bounceOutLeft hidden');
};
```

or this :

```
showLeft.onclick = function() {
    var $li = $(".cbp-spmenu-open ul li.inview");
    if($li.hasClass('visible'))
        $li.removeClass('bounceInLeft visible').addClass('bounceOutLeft hidden');
    else
        $li.removeClass('bounceOutLeft hidden').addClass('bounceInLeft visible');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You just want to replace `visible` with `hidden` and `bounceIn` with `bounceOut`

```
.toggleClass("bounceInLeft visible").toggleClass("bounceOutLeft hidden");
```

and use `addClass` for `animated`, which you want to keep.

See [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/yzzyd96q/)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
showLeft.onclick = function() {
    if($(".cbp-spmenu-open ul li.inview").hasClass('hidden')) {
        $(".cbp-spmenu-open ul li.inview").toggleClass("animated bounceInLeft visible");
    } else {
        $(".cbp-spmenu-open ul li.inview").toggleClass("animated bounceOutLeft hidden");
    }
}
```

It checks whether your element is hidden or not and make it visible or not.

Comment: fixed, don't understand the instant -1

Answer (score 0):

In your html (if possible) try to add `bounceOutLeft` and `hidden` to the `li.inview` element

If not add them with jquery on page load.

```
$(".cbp-spmenu-open ul li.inview").addClass("bounceOutLeft hidden"); // only when you can't edit the html
showLeft.onclick = function() {
  $(".cbp-spmenu-open ul li.inview").toggleClass("animated bounceOutLeft bounceInLeft visible hidden");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
showLeft.onclick = function() {
    if($(".cbp-spmenu-open ul li.inview").hasClass("hidden")
        $(".cbp-spmenu-open ul li.inview").toggleClass("animated bounceInLeft visible");
    else
       $(".cbp-spmenu-open ul li.inview").toggleClass("animated bounceOutLeft hidden");
};
```